# Checking if vector passes through vertices c++

Tags: c++

How can I check if a vector that starts at one point passes through another one point?
It is on two-dimensional coordinates.
Mainly uses c ++, but other languages are possible.

```
float2 startToTarget = target - start;
    if ((startToTarget.x) * vec.y - (startToTarget.y) * vec.x >= -floatingPoint && (startToTarget.x) * vec.y - (startToTarget.y) * vec.x <= floatingPoint)
        if ((startToTarget.x) * vec.x + (startToTarget.y) * vec.y >= -floatingPoint && (startToTarget.x) * vec.x + (startToTarget.y) * vec.y <= floatingPoint) intersecting = true;
```

Comment: Q should be more exact. Number of dimensions?  By vector starting at a point, do you actually mean a line ("ray")?  And it's a pure linear algebra question

Comment: The vector means the direction in which the length exists.
2D space means that only x and y coordinates exist.

Comment: say a vector with a - b
a and b are points.

Comment: Floating point numbers are imprecise. So what you actually want to do is calculate the distance of a point from a line. Google should give you the formula. And then you need to check if the distance is small enough (it will practically never be 0 because of the inaccuracy and lack of infinite precision).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate cross product of vector `d` (direction) and `AB` vector. If result is zero, then these vectors are collinear, so `B` point lies on the line, defined by point `A` and direction vector `d`.

To check direction, evaluate also dot product, it's sign is positive, when  direction `d` coincides with direction `AB`

```
abx = B.x - A.x;
aby = B.y - A.y;

    //cross product           //dot product
if (abs(abx*dy - aby*dx) < 1.0e-10 and abx*dx + aby*dy>0) 
   {B lies on the ray A+d}
```

Comment: Since it is a 2d space, there is no need to be a foreign enemy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this comment. My answer refers to 2D case.

Comment: My mistake
I understood the foreign enemy in another direction.
Anyway, the instantaneous value using the inner product will change the result.
Dot product cannot be used immediately.
Is there any other way?

Comment: I think this is the simplest way.

Comment: No. There is some issue - for cross product floating math errors might give not exact zero value, so it is worth to compare abs(cross) with small epsylon value.

Comment: thx bro.But it cannot be used because of the dot product.

Comment: Why dot product is not possible?

Comment: Is it correct to implement like the source code added to the text?
The result is strange.

Comment: Yes. Example: `A = (0,0), d = (1,1), B = (3,3).  abx = 3, aby=3, 3*1-3*1==0, 3*1+3*1=6>0`

Comment: When the inner product is used, the larger the value of (a - b), the larger the error.
Isn't it?

Comment: As far as I understand, term inner product refers to dot( scalar) product. It's precision is not important here. Cross product (part of vector product)  value is doubled area of triangle from points (A;B,A+d) and yes, it's precision depends on AB components. You can scale epsylon value with multiplication by max(abx, aby) if needed (in the most cases using `eps` like `1.e-10` is sufficient)

Comment: I think there is a translation fail here. "foreign enemy", "cannot use dot product"..